# Xamarin - IOS Simulator - Cannot connect to local Webservice (VS 2019 for Windows)

Tags: xamarin.ios, webservice-client

I have a mobile app that consumes webservices.
I can run the webservices locally under an 'admini' instance of visual studio over http.
Android emulator connects without isssue (now) via 10.2.2.0:
All good there.

However - I am unable to get the IOS simulator to do the same.
I have my webservices running and having the bindings configured to serve over my machines IP:.
I can browse locally to this OK in a browser.
I can browse OK to it on the Mac on which the simulator is running in Safari.

However, I always get a 500 response from HTTP request in the app itself.

What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In this instance - it turned out that the first line in the controller was attempting to send an email and as the smpt server was not available would throw an exception which was not handled.
Thus the response was a 500.

I discoverd this by viewing debug output from the webservice and seeing an smtp exception gave me the clue.
Lesson learned.

I would say to anyone experiencing similar - to attempt to connect and see if there is any output/activity on the server side.